# How to get ImageProcessor.Web to work nicely with ServiceStack

Tags: .net, imageprocessor

(http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor-web/)

If I use the provided `web.config` it stops servicestack from working, even though ServiceStack is placed nicely under location `path="api"`

I think I'll use another caching method, but as FYI for the developer. If I try to put it under location `path="images"` as per full `web.config` below it does nothing at all:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="api">
    <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <handlers>
        <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>

  <location path="images">
    <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <modules>
        <add name="ImageProcessorModule" type="ImageProcessor.Web.HttpModules.ImageProcessingModule, ImageProcessor.Web" />
      </modules>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I'm gonna need more than this to help you I'm afraid. What version? What additional debugging steps have you taken. What do you even mean by "stops working"?

Comment: I just Installed via Nuget today, by stop working I mean Servicestack routes can no longer be found (they don't work at all together).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot add modules to a specific path, jsut by using the  element. You will need to create a virtual application for that. This also means that you will need to but the needed dll's in that locations bin folder.

Something like this structure:

- /root
- - /bin
- - - yourApp.dll
- - /images
- - - /bin
- - - - ImageProcessor*.dll
- - - yourimg.jpg
- - - web.config
- - web.config